# Run query every time a SQL Server Agent job runs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have around 100 SQL Server Agent jobs that run on schedules. I need a way to execute a query and dump the results every time one of those jobs runs into a table. Something like

```
[Job Name], [Success/Fail], [Time] etc.
```

The table is a custom table but I can be flexible with it. Google has turned up answers in all the wrong directions.

Comment: Agent can store execution history in `msdb.sysjobsteplogs` table. Does it not work for you ? You can query it and periodically pull data to your custom table if needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not check log file for SQL Server Agent?

**[View SQL Server Agent Error Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191008.aspx)**

[image]

You can also manually query **[`dbo.sysjobhistory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx)** and/or **[`dbo.sysjobactivity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190484.aspx)**:

> **dbo.sysjobhistory**
>
> Contains information about the execution of scheduled jobs by SQL
>   Server Agent. This table is stored in the msdb database.
>
> **dbo.sysjobactivity**
>
> Records current SQL Server Agent job activity and status.

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
```

Comment: I need it in a database so I can query it for an application I have to build.

Comment: And I don't just need errors, I  need information anytime something runs.

Comment: @BryantFrankford Log contains all logs successful also